# Django 'ModelBase' object is not iterable TypeError

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Getting the below from a unit test in Django. Can't seem to figure out the reason this is happening.

My migrations look identical to the other migrations I have made.

Also, I was able to run this on my local machine in the admin section, so my other question is this big deal if it is happening during the test if it can be pushed live. Trying to follow best practices here, so appreciate others' opinions on that.

models.py

```
class LeadComplete(models.Model):
    """Complete lead info"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    )
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time_minutes = models.IntegerField()
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    client = models.ManyToManyField('Client')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
class LeadCompleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize a leadComplete"""
    client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Client.objects.all()
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = LeadComplete
        fields = [
            'id', 'title', 'time_minutes', 'score', 'link', 'client',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

views.py

```
class LeadCompleteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Manage LeadComplete in the database"""
    serializer_class = serializers.LeadCompleteSerializer
    queryset = LeadComplete.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Retrieve the leadcomplete for the authed user"""
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

test_lead_complete_api.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from rest_framework import status 
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from core. models import LeadComplete

from leads.serializers import LeadCompleteSerializer

LEADCOMPLETE_URL = reverse('leads:leadcomplete-list')

def sample_leadComplete(user, **params):
    """Create and return a sample leadComplete"""
    defaults = {
        'title': 'Samle Company',
        'time_minutes': 10,
        'score': 5.00,
    }
    defaults.update(params)

    return LeadComplete.objects.create(user=user, **defaults)

def PublicLeadCompleteApiTests(TestCase):
    """Test unauthenticated LeacComplete access"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_auth_required(self):
        """"Test that authentication is required"""
        res = selft.client.get(LEADCOMPLETE_URL)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    
class PrivateLeadCompleteApiTests(TestCase):
    """"Test authenticated recipe API access"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            'test@unionresolute.com',
            'testpass'
        )
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)

    def test_retrieve_leadComplete(self):
        """Test retrieving LeadComplete list"""
        sample_leadComplete(user=self.user)
        sample_leadComplete(user=self.user)

        res = self.client.get(LEADCOMPLETE_URL)

        leadComplete = LeadComplete.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        serializer = LeadCompleteSerializer(LeadComplete, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)

    def test_leadComplete_limited_to_user(self):
        """Test retrieving leadComplete for user"""
        user2 = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            'other@unionresolute.com',
            'password123'
        )
        sample_leadComplete(user=user2)
        sample_leadComplete(user=self.user)

        res = self.client.get(LEADCOMPLETE_URL)

        leadComplete = LeadComplete.objects.filter(user=self.user)
        serializer = LeadCompleteSerializer(leadComplete, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
```

error:

```
ERROR: test_retrieve_leadComplete (leads.tests.test_leadcomplete_api.PrivateLeadCompleteApiTests)
Test retrieving LeadComplete list
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/leads/tests/test_leadcomplete_api.py", line 58, in test_retrieve_leadComplete
    self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 768, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

The test client returns data in the content property.

Try `res.content` instead of `res.data`

```
def test_retrieve_leadComplete(self):
    """Test retrieving LeadComplete list"""
    sample_leadComplete(user=self.user)
    sample_leadComplete(user=self.user)

    res = self.client.get(LEADCOMPLETE_URL)

    leadComplete = LeadComplete.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer = LeadCompleteSerializer(LeadComplete, many=True)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(res.content, serializer.data)
```